# Removing Duplicate Tag Content Using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python-2.7, web, web-scraping

I made a Script for Getting every H1 Tag from all 76 pages of a website. But in this process my Program copy a very specific line "Current Affairs January 2015" as this line is present in every page. Can I edit the Code to just print it 1 time ?

Here's my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import urllib


for i in range(2,77):
    url1="http://currentaffairs.gktoday.in/month/current-affairs-january-2015/"+"page/"+str(i)
    soup = bs(urllib.urlopen(url1))
    for link in soup.findAll('h1'):
        print link.string
```

[image: Here is the Screenshot of the output]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import urllib


for i in range(2,77):
    url1="http://currentaffairs.gktoday.in/month/current-affairs-january-2015/"+"page/"+str(i)
    soup = bs(urllib.urlopen(url1))
    uLinks = soup.findAll('h1')
    for index, item in enumerate(uLinks): 
          if i == 2:                
                print(item.string)                
          if i != 2:
                if index != 0:                                            
                      print(item.string)
```